# Не работает диалоговое окно

Tags: java, javafx

Посмотрел руководство по диалоговым окнам. Скопировал код. А он не работает(

```
public static void showInfoDialog(String title, String text){
    Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
    alert.setTitle("Information Dialog");
    alert.setHeaderText("Look, an Information Dialog");
    alert.setContentText("I have a great message for you!");

    alert.showAndWait();
}
```

Comment: А что тут не работает?

Comment: Не хочет компилироваться.     
Error:(48, 5) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class MyTool
  location: class sample.ControllerCreateNewBuildMods

Comment: 48 строчка - это которая?

Comment: Она в другом классе. MyTool myTool = new MyTool(); В классе MyTool находится этот метод

Comment: Проблема не в этом коде. Если проблема и в этом методе, то скорее всего, что не объявлен импорт для алерта. Код рабочий

Comment: Ругается на         alert.showAndWait();

Comment: Что пишет? Когда ругается?

Comment: А если просто `show()`?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб у просто show() нельзя получить нажатую кнопку.